# How to modify this function for argument usage

Tags: c++, function, vector

i have this function with constructor:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>>& getTrainSet()  { return trainSet; }
void setTrainSet(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& trainSet) { this->trainSet = trainSet; }
```

Which is called like this:

```
testNet.setTrainSet(std::vector<std::vector<double>>() = {
        { 1.0, 1.0, 0.73 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.81 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.86 },
        { 1.0, 1.0, 0.95 },{ 1.0, 0.0, 0.45 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.70 },
        { 1.0, 0.0, 0.51 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.89 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.79 },{ 1.0, 0.0, 0.54 } 
        });
```

How do I modify this function so it will let me pass my variables like this:
`testNet.setTrainSet(vector);`

Comment: You just need to remove the `std::vector<std::vector<double>>() = ` part.

Comment: Side note: Consider whether or not you want these accessor functions at all. It is generally better to provide functions that manipulate the class data than it is to give class data for outsiders to manipulate and then send back.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in two ways,

1. Declaring it first and then passing,

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec = {
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.73 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.81 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.86 },
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.95 }, { 1.0, 0.0, 0.45 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.70 },
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.51 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.89 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.79 },
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.54 }
};

testNet.setTrainSet(vec);
```

2. or by passing it directly into the setter.

```cpp
testNet.setTrainSet({
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.73 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.81 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.86 },
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.95 }, { 1.0, 0.0, 0.45 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.70 },
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.51 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.89 }, { 1.0, 1.0, 0.79 },
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.54 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to declare the vector before calling the function?

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec = {
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.73 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.81 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.86 },
    { 1.0, 1.0, 0.95 },{ 1.0, 0.0, 0.45 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.70 },
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.51 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.89 },{ 1.0, 1.0, 0.79 },{ 1.0, 0.0, 0.54 } 
    });
testNet.setTrainSet(vec);
```